# Loading the HTML while still working in Django (probably through asynchronous functions)

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, optimization, web-scraping

I have [this project](https://github.com/Grumpy-Kat/WebScraping) that I’ve been working on for a while:

In the `views.py` file, I scrape a lot of information from IMDB, with each call taking around 0.3 of a second. Meanwhile, my page will stand idle. I want to have it load the page and then finish up the call.

For instance, I want it to load the recommended movies after already showing the actors and actresses that played in both. Or in an index, I want to allow the user to type and then show the options to click on.
I’ve tried Celery with Redis, but Django can’t display asynchronous tasks.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Django can't do that. My advice would be to divide and conquer:

1. First, write a view that just displays some HTML to load a JS script that can load your data asynchronously, using the render shortcut. A front-end framework like Vue can help you to hide the parts of your layout while your data loads.
2. Next, write views that just return the data using the JsonResponse object in Django, for example: one view to load the recommendations, one view to load the actor list.
3. Use XH requests to call your views and retrieve the information, using the Promise methods to make everything appear in sync.
4. Bonus: If you already have Celery in place, you can define a task that grabs all the data you need on the server, and create a view that polls the status of your task, and then call it using XHR every few milliseconds until your data (or part of it, that really depends on how you define your task) is ready.

Comment: Would it be possible to do it using JavaScript? I was thinking of trying to have celery pass JavaScript the info it returned and then display it. This method would make is easy to implement a loading sign too. Could this work?